# Node.js buffer vs slow buffer

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, performance

I made a c++ binding for handling buffers to maximize performance but the C++ add-on returns to node.js a `slowBuffer`.

Now does this mean it is slower than just using the `Buffer` of node.js instead?

The C++ add-on does some heavy calculations on the buffer. Having read this somewhere:

> Using C++ modules from the native Javascript environment costs extra
>   CPU time, hence the "slow".

Does this now mean that it made my Node.js application slow? I am confused.

Comment: SlowBuffers are slow to create from javascript, nothing more

Comment: So making a C++ add-on to handle the number crunching instead of it being javascript just made it slower?

Comment: That's possible, depends on number crunching / js value allocation ratio.

Comment: hmmm, too bad. I really thought I'd be able to improve performance if I made the module a c++ add-on instead.

Comment: Once again, it's POSSIBLE to make things faster, but no guarantee